# Ubuntu One doesn't share some of my directories

Tags: ubuntu-one

I have Ubuntu One installed in my Ubuntu 13.04 laptop and inside a Windows7 virtual machine.

The main Ubuntu One directory is in sync, this is Ok.

I use this Win7 virtual machine only to use my desktop scanner. This vm collects all my scans inside a directory `.../Scans`.

I have configured Ubuntu One inside the Windows 7 virtual machine to sync this `.../Scans` directory too - I have checked the `sync locally` checkbox associated with this folder. It seems to work, synchronizing has been under processing, and the size allocated on the ubuntu cloud drive has grown up slowly, percent by percent. Now it shows "Files SYnc is up to date". So I should say the Ubuntu One service is working.

My problem: If I check the Ubuntu One directory inside my linux Ubuntu 13.04 laptop, the sync folder and its data won't appear ?

What should I do so as my linux Ubuntu 13.04 has access to this `Scans/` directory that is in sync with my win7 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check "sync locally" on your Ubuntu 13.04 client too. To ensure that your .../scans file is uploaded to the cloud, you should explore your files from [Ubuntu One](http://one.ubuntu.com)
and see if this file is uploaded.

If yes, then you haven't checked the "sync locally" in you Ubuntu 13.04 too.

Comment: and how do I check the "sync locally" inside ubuntu 13.04 ?

Comment: Open "Ubuntu One" app and tick check "always in sync" on the file "scans"